# How to load VM Stat CSV file to Load runner analysis tool

Tags: loadrunner

I have used load runner analysis to analyse server resource utilization for Perfmon counters of windows servers.I want to use load runner analysis tool to analyse linux VM Stats csv file.
Does anyone got any solution on how to do this.

Comment: Please provide more context and show us what you tried so far, especially any code. If this question is not code related, please consider posting to Serverfault and delete here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The import format is covered in the analysis documentation and help file.  A straight VMStat output file may lake some key fields related to date and time which are required for the import.  However, if you know the end time for creation of the file and the interval at which your samples are taken, such as once every 10 seconds, then you can certainly write a small program to convert from your default format to the format you need for import.   See the documentation related to import of external data.

Comment: I tried to add 2 rows of date and time in vmstat file but still it is not getting accepted could you please suggest what is the format I need to convert vmstat file into

Comment: http://lrhelp.saas.hpe.com/en/latest/help/WebHelp/Content/Analysis/106400_r_supported_file_types.htm

Comment: Im having issue with importing vmstat this format to loadrunner analysis any thought on this ?                                                                                 
Fri Jun 16 01:59:01 2  0  56168 116192 102756 1302596    0    0     2     9   14   13  2  0 98  0  0

Comment: See the link on the Feb 25,'16 comment.  Your format does not appear to match the available formats for import, so you will likely need to massage your output to match your input needs....or massage your output at the point of collection to match your input need to analysis